# winkey + TAB behavior of win7 - I want it back in win10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, task-view

I just upgraded from win7 to win10

Quite fine - but -BUT- I m really missing the win7 behavior when pressing winkey and TAB - in win7 there was a kind of a rolling slideshow in win10 there is a boring collection of dumb little screenphotos of the tasks running. I really want my win7 winkey+Tab behavior back, how can I manage that beside the option of rolling back my win10 installation to win7. Its a really k.o. criteria for win10 for me

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to downgrade. That feature was removed. No way (in my knowledge) to bring it back.